# Someone from my office gave negative review of company and posted wrong things about my character

Tags: work-environment, india, conflict-resolution

A guy from my company posted a bad review of our company on Mouthshut where he wrote bad things about the company and named some female employees including me saying they do prostitution. I was surfing the Internet when I happened to see it. I feel very humiliated about it as I am very friendly with him in office.

I want the post to be removed.  I know it was him, though I'm sure he'll deny it if challenged.  How should I pursue that goal?

Comment: Assuming this is in the US, I strongly recommend getting a screenshot and an attorney. This sounds like potentially libel AND sexual harassment. They are harming not only you, but also the others they've named. You should consider bringing this to their attention as well. The fact that the post is supposedly anonymous is probably irrelevant, it is quite possible to link that post to a real person with a good supeana or threat thereof.

Comment: @Glen Pierce this is in India

Comment: If there are actual names in the review it's probably against the websites rules where it's posted on. Check the website and see if you can report the review.

Comment: If you had proof that it's him, you can potentially speak to HR about it. Otherwise it's mostly about getting something removed from a website, which isn't really a Workplace issue (your options would be somewhere between reaching out to the website or consulting a lawyer).

Comment: Bring it to the attention of your manager without naming the colleague. I'd expect that your company then will take at least steps to have it removed from the website.

Comment: FWIW, I've emailed Mouthshut and pointed them to this question. Sometimes in cases like this the company itself wants to respond directly, which can be helpful.

Comment: I'd think that Mouthshut would be pretty helpful in shutting down something like that, since it's clearly disparaging and would require a pretty high burden of proof to make that claim.  Having it out there based on no evidence would expose them to a lot of liability.

Comment: How do you know that 100% it is written by him? Seems like there is a hidden story....

Comment: Careful of saying you know somebody did something, if they actually didn’t, they could have a case of for slander.  Concentrate on getting the post taken down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A guy from my company posted a bad review of our company on Mouthshut where he wrote bad things about the company and named some female employees including me saying they do prostitution.
>
> ...
>
> I know it was him, though I'm sure he'll deny it if challenged.

I would ignore who wrote the post entirely, as mixing up accusations in this isn't helpful. If your boss wants to find that out later, let that be up to him to resolve.

Mouthshut might not want to do anything with the bad comments made about the company, but they may well take down any comments about names of female employees doing prostitution. (They may not of course, but it's definitely worth a shot.) I would email them with a link to the review and ask that they at least remove the names of the female employees based on the above.

In parallel with the above, you should also make your boss aware of the post and ask him to instigate steps to get it removed, or at least the personal part (your names) removed. He may be able to escalate it up the chain of command, and get legal help if needed.